# python(2.7) function takes the multiple integers and a list, and return an integer and a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, return-type

If you see the players.py file code below, three integers and one list are used as input arguments of the first_player(). And I want return of the function to be a list and an integer(I need only one for return). However I only get an empty list. How can I recall a list and an integer in this case?

---

```
def dealing():

    player1 = list()
    start_drawing = 0
    nc = 0
    cards = L_shuffle_deck.shuffle_deck()
    n = len(cards) - 1 # n = 51    
    while start_drawing < 2:
        players.first_player(player1, n, nc, cards)
        start_drawing += 1
        nc += 1

    print player1

    ...
```

## players.py  below..

```
def first_player(player1, n, nc, cards):

    player1 = player1 + [cards[n]]                   
    card_order = player1                             
    changing = conv_cards.assigning(nc, card_order)  
    player1[nc] = changing[nc]                       
    cards = cards[:n]                                
    n -= 1                                           

    return player1, n #doesn't work
    #I want my output to be player1(list), n(integer)
```

Comment: Can you [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31016894/edit) your question with the full traceback for the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory look at your code, it appears you return values from your function, but you don't assign those values to any variable(s).

Try this in your `dealing` function:

```
...
player1, n = players.first_player(player1, n, nc, cards)
...
```

Comment: I thought I tried it before, but I wasn't. It worked beautifully! Thanks a lot!